# How to access template parent context

Tags: ractivejs

Assuming the code bellow or something similar to it, how do I pass the parent context in the {{each} context, or how do i access it from the on-click event. Thank you.

```
<div>
      <ul>
           {{#each emoticons[emoticons.state.selected].iconList}}
                <li on-mouseover="showEmoticonBig" on-click="@this.fire('selectEmoticon',event,this)" class="emoticons-icon">{{{parseToIcons(.code)}}}</li>
            {{/each}}
      </ul>
 </div

    ractObj.off("selectEmoticon").on("selectEmoticon", function (event,context) {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`ractive.fire` accepts at least 1 argument - the event name. Everything after that becomes the event arguments. On the other side, on the event handler, it accepts at least 1 argument, the event object that's implicitly provided. Everything after that are the arguments passed by `ractive.fire`.

In this case, `@this.fire` will not need `event` passed in explicitly. It should simply be `@this.fire('selectEmoticon',this)`. This will make `context` on your handler refer to whatever `this` was in the call.